# MPC Mode in GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

I just need clarification about the definition of the prediction and control horizon in MPC mode in GEKKO. In the examples found online (For example here https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabF), a horizon is defined with m.time(), with m our GEKKO model. In MPC mode (IMODE =6), Is this the prediction horizon of the control horizonß?

Answer (score 2):

In APMonitor, there is the concept of [Control Horizon](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmCtrlHor) and [Prediction Horizon](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmPredHor). This is common in advanced control software where you want to calculate a move plan during the control horizon but then keep the last value in the control horizon and predict to steady state with the predict horizon. Gekko is more flexible in allowing any sequence of time points in control / prediction horizon. All of the horizon is a control horizon so the MV values are adjustable across the entire time horizon. If you need to reduce the degrees of freedom for faster solution then I recommend the [MV_STEP_HOR (MV Step Horizon) parameter](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionMvStepHor) that can be adjusted with `m.options.MV_STEP_HOR = 2`. Here are [common tuning parameters](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerTuning) in Gekko for MPC applications.

[image: MPC tuning]

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Hedengren